# Mounting android phone to android tablet

Tags: mount, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace, with Android 2.3; and an android tablet with USB host support, running on 4.0.3.

When I connect the phone to the tablet with an OTG cable, tablet says SD card is broken, and that I need to format it.

The tablet is rooted and I have Debian on it, which is run alongside android (With the help of Sven Ola's 'Debian Kit').

Is there a way to mount phone FS on the tablet?

Answer (score 0):

I think that 'broken' means 'unsupported file system'. You can try searching for solution even just in Play Store. I had similar situations what I tried to connect ntfs pendrive to smartphone. [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paragon.tcplugins_ntfs_ro) helped me, but I feel like You do not have ntfs file system there.

Hope that it somehow helps.